# How to enable uninstall for a Wix bundle and still hide it from Programs and features?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

I do not want to display my bundle in Programs and features. But when uninstalling it should be removed along with the MSIs. In order to hide the the bundle I can set disableModify property to yes. This will hide the bundle. But this will disable the uninstall feature for the bundle. That is not what I want. Because How can I hide the bundle from Programs and Features and still uninstall it during an uninstall? Please advice.

Comment: Not including a bundle in Programs and Features does just that. The very same uninstall command will still uninstall it. (That probably doesn't help but it is something you should know.)

Comment: I hid it from Programs and features and uninstalled my app. Then when I run the installer again with a version lower than what I had previously, installer says there is already a higher version. Though I just uninstalled that higher version. This behavior is not there if I don't hide the exe. Why is that then? :(

Answer (score 1):

From the [perspective of the bundle](https://www.joyofsetup.com/2013/07/05/burn-zero-one-or-n/), there is no "app", only 0 or more packages.

From the perspective of a package installer (e.g., .msi), there is no bundle. It could have been installed/referenced by 0 or more bundles and/or installed manually or some other system.

Uninstalling a package "breaks" the bundle. It could be repaired or uninstalled with the same bundle version itself but it can't be repaired by installing a lower versioned bundle.

The most straightforward approach is to hide your application-specific packages from Programs and Features and let the users view the bundle as "the application". (Any packages your bundle treats as permanent should typically not be hidden.)

Comment: How do you allow for Repair and Modify actions on the resulting MSI, if it is hidden in ARP?  I agree, this works, but it neuters the MSI(s).

Comment: Any of the bundles that reference an MSI package can be visible in ARP so there is an opportunity for users to manually invoke a repair. Also this doesn't affect MSI auto-repair nor the ability to invoke a repair of bundle or MSI via command-line.

Comment: The trouble then, if you show the msi in ARP, then you essentially have a duplicate entry.  If you have MyApp.msi and need to wrap it in a bootstrapper (MyApp.exe), then, you will have entries for MyApp from the bootstrapper and MyApp from the MSI.

Comment: @Jon This would lead you back to hiding the MSI(s) that are the essence of, and owned by, an "application bundle". It is not widely appreciated that the bundle engine ("burn") is a package manager. Some avoid it because of that. But if you do use it, your decisions should be based on it being a package manager.

Answer (score 1):

The Visible="yes" will show you the installed packages separately.

```
<MsiPackage Id="Dependency1" SourceFile="your.msi" Cache="no" Visible="yes"  DisplayInternalUI="yes" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[See this answer about handling MSI and MSP in bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38840748/wix-bundle-patches-for-1-0-0-are-not-removed-from-programs-features-when-bund/38840749#38840749)

It sounds like the behavior you are after.

Note that that answer is for WiX 3.9 or later